# Can anyone help me understand how this code prints a triangle?

Tags: c, nested-for-loop

I don't understand how this code displays a triangle. My main problem is understanding the working of integers j and k. How do they affect the triangle's position?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int j,k,Rows;
    printf("Enter The Number of Rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &Rows);

    for(j=2;j<=l;j++){
        for(k=1;k<=j;k++){
            printf("  %d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `triangle` tag. It's not useful for categorizing the question so let's leave it off.

Comment: @kuldeep singh - No wonder that you _don't understand how this triangle is working_, since the code isn't working at all: `:8:16: error: ‘l’ undeclared`.

Comment: Compile your code with the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Once you have no warnings from the compiler, use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop. Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source software, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the program you want is

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int j,k,Rows;
    printf("Enter The Number of Rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &Rows);

    for(j=1;j<=Rows;j++){
        for(k=1;k<=j;k++){
            printf("  %d ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Changes are:

- Change `l` to `Rows`
- Change `j=2` to `j=1`

And here is an example result

```
Enter The Number of Rows : 6
  1 
  2   2 
  3   3   3 
  4   4   4   4 
  5   5   5   5   5 
  6   6   6   6   6   6
```

> My main problem is understanding the working of integers `j` and `k`. How do they affect the triangle's position?

`j` here can represent the row index. `k` can represent the column index. In another word, `k` represents how many items in current row. `for(k=1;k<=j;k++)` means the max value of `k` is `j`. Since `j` is increased by 1, so the max value of `k` is also increased by 1:

```
口          # j = 1, the max value of k is 1, so this row has 1 item.
口 口       # j = 2, the max value of k is 2, so this row has 2 items.
口 口 口    # j = 3, the max value of k is 3, so this row has 3 items.
口 口 口 口 # j = 4, the max value of k is 4, so this row has 4 items.
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really having a hard time understanding the concept